# Find the domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have been a bit confused about finding the domain of these functions.

1) $\dfrac{12}{2x+3}$

2) $\dfrac{4x-3}{x^2-81}$

3) $\dfrac{x^2 -3x -18}{x-6}$

So I solved for $x$ and then those were the values that could not be part of the domain. These are my answers.

1) Since there are no numbers that make the denominator $0$ on this problem, I put all real numbers.

2) Domain $= \{x \mid x \neq 9, x \neq -9\}$ All numbers but $9$ and $-9$

3) All numbers but $-3$

I don't know if I am doing this right? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I have edited your post. Please be sure I did not introduce any errors.

Answer (score 5):

In all three, the domain is where the denominator of fractions $\neq 0$.

For 1), the denominator of the fraction can equal $0$. Thus, we proceed:

$2x+3\neq 0 \Longrightarrow x\neq \frac{-3}{2}$

For 2), you are correct. We proceed like this:

$x^2-81 \neq 0 \Longrightarrow x\neq \pm 9$

For 3), the function exists at $-3$, and is $0$. The function cannot equal $6$, because

$x-6 \neq 0 \Longrightarrow x\neq 6$.

From this information, can you extract the domains?

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1:

What you say is not true: What about $x=\frac{-3}{2}$?

Problem 2:

Again dealing with only the denominator, the only place this function can have problems, we factor, as you should often try and do:

$$(x^2-81)=(x+9)(x-9)$$ By difference of squares, so $x\ne \pm 9$.

Problem 3:

Check both values where anything could go wrong after factoring the numerator. Checking -3 and 6, you see that -3 exists, but 6 does not.

Which tells you $x\ne 6$

Comment: Removed -1. Nice answer!

Comment: @zz20s thanks, can't believed I messed that up

Comment: If we cancel $x - 6$, we are left with $x + 3$, not its reciprocal.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The poster has edited since.